# API for Kernel Module Development

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I want to know if there is an API documentation listing all the `functions/methods` in the Header files? E.g. `linux/kernel.h` listing functions like `printk()`, `linux/moduleparam.h` indicating functions like `module_param()`?

I just want to have a holistic understanding of the functions and not copying piece-meal used by textbooks.